# Create hyperlink to another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a hyperlink created in VBA which will jump to a specific cell when clicked, similar to an HTML anchor link.

For instance:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(1, 2), Address:=range("B23"), TextToDisplay:="Test Link"
```

However the above doesn't work as it says address not found

Comment: You forgot an `=` sign after `TextToDisplay:`

Comment: @findwindow = thanks for catching that!

Comment: Compliment from @Jeeped Feels good^^

Comment: @findwindow, ah thanks edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `SubAddress` parameter of the [Hyperlinks.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx), not the `Address`.

```
with ActiveSheet
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1, 2), _
                    Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:= .Name & "!$B$23", _
                    TextToDisplay:="Test Link"
end with
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that way:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("E5"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:="Sheet1!A1"
```